# телеграм бот повтор выбора кнопок

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть бот: При запуске появляется выбор кнопок. Юзер нажимает одну из, получает выборку из базы. Как сделать чтоб после выборки данных из базы опять появлялся выбор кнопок. Без рестарта. Если не затруднит, примером. Спасибо.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Нажмите одну из кнопок", reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full)


    @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button1')
    async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
        button_push = callback_query
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, config.switch_button.get(button_push))
        print(button_push.data)
        push = button_push.data
        button_request = config.switch_button.get(push)
        print(button_request)
        con = pymysql.connect(host='', user='', password='', database='')
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(button_request)
            rows = cur.fetchone()
            print(rows)
            await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В последней строчке:

```py
await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, rows)
```

Заменить на

```py
await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, rows, reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full)
```